# cannot establish ssh connection, /bin/bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, localhost

I am trying to test the ssh service on my ubuntu 18.04 odroid-xu4 device, before yesterday everything was working just fine and I able to access the odroid device form my windows pc int the same LAN witout any problem, now when I try to ssh localhost I get the following output in the terminal

```
odroid@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.14.157-171 armv7l)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

* Latest Kubernetes 1.18 beta is now available for your laptop, NUC, cloud
  instance or Raspberry Pi, with automatic updates to the final GA release.

 sudo snap install microk8s --channel=1.18/beta --classic

* Multipass 1.1 adds proxy support for developers behind enterprise
firewalls. Rapid prototyping for cloud operations just got easier.

 https://multipass.run/

74 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Thu Mar 19 11:57:11 2020 from ::1
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Connection to localhost closed.
```

This is the content of the sshd_config file

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
Match Group sftp_users
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ChrootDirectory /home
#ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

What could be the possible issue that is causing this problem and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the shell you are using.

```sh
me@my-machine$ ssh root@myhost -t sh
```

Here is a complete answer: https://serverfault.com/a/977106

Comment: Okay, it worked when I changed the shell I can now establish the ssh session, is there a way to force the use of the sh shell instead of the bash one ?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the **/etc/passwd** file and change the shell for the user you use to login via ssh